# Play project compiles successfully but IDEA cannot resolve symbols while importing dependencies

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

Piece of build.sbt related to Play! application project.

```
resolvers += Resolver.jcenterRepo,
resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.kyleu" %% "jdub-async" % "1.0",
    "com.vmunier" %% "play-scalajs-scripts" % "0.3.0",
    "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "1.11.1",
    "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11",
    evolutions,
    "com.github.benhutchison" %% "prickle" % "1.1.7",
    specs2 % Test
  )
```

IDEA said to me that it cannot resolve symbol jdub when I import jdub-async library. Meanwhile project is compiling successfully.

How is it possible to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an issue with IntelliJ IDEA's own Scala compiler. It chokes on many things. If it compiles fine with SBT itself, you don't have any bug to resolve (unless you want to report it to IntelliJ).

Comment: You are right. It's an IDEA bug. "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart" helped me though.